# Need help with android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT and SharedPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have a main activity where I call

```
VersionSettings vs = new VersionSettings(this);
    if (vs.firstRun2()) 
        vs.versionCheckbox();
```

What I'm trying to do is set a checkbox (checkboxVideoType) to an unchecked state if the Android version is 1.6-2.1

I only want to do this the very first time the app is ever run, it never needs to run again.

I think I'm running into the problem when the main activity calls versionCheckbox(), I get a force close if it attempts to run the code inside that is going to set the checkbox to false.

I'm very new to programming and would really appreciate some help with this. I think I'm close, but need a push. Thanks in advance!

Main Activity

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;



public class Nasatv extends Activity implements OnClickListener  {

boolean checkboxIsChecked;
SharedPreferences nasaTV_Prefs;




@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.window_title);

    nasaTV_Prefs = getSharedPreferences("nasaTV_Prefs", 0);

    ChangeLog cl = new ChangeLog(this);
    if (cl.firstRun())
        cl.getLogDialog().show();

    VersionSettings vs = new VersionSettings(this);
    if (vs.firstRun2()) 
        vs.versionCheckbox();


    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(this); 


    Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Nasatv.this, LaunchCalendar.class);
            startActivity(i);          

        }
    });


    Button button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Nasatv.this, PhotoInfo.class);
            startActivity(i);   
        }
    }); 


    CheckConnectivity check = new CheckConnectivity();
    Boolean conn = check.checkNow(this.getApplicationContext());
    if(conn == true){
        ImageView updateImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.updateImage);
        ImageDownloader downloader = new ImageDownloader(updateImage);
        downloader.execute("http://www.url.com/trl/ubox.jpg");
    } else {
        ImageView updateImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.updateImage);
        updateImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.uboxerror);
    } 
}




public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);
    return true;
}


public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
{
    switch (item.getItemId()) 
    {
        case R.id.setting_title:
            Intent settingsActivity =new Intent(getBaseContext(), Settings.class);
            startActivity(settingsActivity);
            return true;

        case R.id.photo_archive:
            Intent archive = new Intent(Nasatv.this, PhotoArchive.class);
            startActivity(archive);
            return true;

        case R.id.n_web:
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,     Uri.parse("http://www.nasa.gov/"));
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;

        case R.id.exit_title:
            finish();
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}



public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    checkboxIsChecked = nasaTV_Prefs.getBoolean("checkboxVideoType", true);
}



@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (checkboxIsChecked) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,     Uri.parse("http://www.nasa.gov/multimedia/nasatv/nasatv_android_flash.html"));
         startActivity(intent);
    } else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,     Uri.parse("rtsp://nasadln.qt.llnwd.net/nasa101.sdp"));
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}


}
```

One-time run class

```
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.content.SharedPreferences;
 import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.widget.CheckBox;



      public class VersionSettings {

    private final Context context;
    private String notRun, hasRun;
    private SharedPreferences run;
    private CheckBox checkboxVideoType;
    private SharedPreferences nasaTV_Prefs;
    private static final String HAS_RUN = "PREFS_HAS_RUN";


int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;

/**
 * Constructor
 *
 * Retrieves whether the app has been run or not and saves to
 * SharedPreferences
 */
    public VersionSettings(Context context) {
    this.context = context;

    this.run = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

    // get run/not run string number, which is "1"
    this.notRun = run.getString(HAS_RUN, "");
    Log.d(TAG, "notRun: " + notRun);
    this.hasRun = context.getResources().getString(R.string.has_run_string);
    Log.d(TAG, "hasRun: " + hasRun);

    // save new number to preferences, which will be the same number, 
    // so this is run only the very first time the app is run
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = run.edit();
    editor.putString(HAS_RUN, hasRun);
    editor.commit();
}


/**
 * @return  true if this version of your app is started for the first
 *          time
 */
public boolean firstRun2() {
    return  ! notRun.equals(hasRun);
} 


/**
 * @return  Change the checkboxVideoType to "unchecked" (false)
 *          
 */
public void versionCheckbox() {
//  this.context = context;

        if (currentapiVersion < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO){

            this.nasaTV_Prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = nasaTV_Prefs.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("checkboxVideoType", false);
            editor.commit();
        }
}

private static final String TAG = "VersionSettings";
}
```

Preferences Activity

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;

public class Settings extends Activity implements OnCheckedChangeListener {

private CheckBox checkboxVideoType;
private SharedPreferences nasaTV_Prefs;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);

            setContentView(R.layout.preferences);

            getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.window_title);

            checkboxVideoType  =  (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkboxVideoType);
            checkboxVideoType.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
            nasaTV_Prefs = getSharedPreferences("nasaTV_Prefs", 0);
            checkboxVideoType.setChecked(nasaTV_Prefs.getBoolean("checkboxVideoType", true));



            Button clbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clbutton);
            clbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                ChangeLog cl = new ChangeLog(Settings.this);
                cl.getFullLogDialog().show();

        }
    });

    }

    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton cb, boolean isChecked) {

          if (cb == checkboxVideoType){                     
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = nasaTV_Prefs.edit();  
            editor.putBoolean("checkboxVideoType", isChecked);
            editor.commit();        // Commit the edit, i.e.,     save the state of the flag!
          }
    }

}
```

Comment: Get rid of this line: `nasaTV_Prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("nasaTV_Prefs", 0);`, you're getting an instance of the default preferences on the next line and storing it in the same variables, so it's unneeded. Where are you calling the `versionCheckbox()` method? I would need to know to help further.

Comment: I'm calling it in my main Activity, in OnCreate, just after the setContentView. I don't believe there is a problem there as I'm calling a similar method in the same spot (which I based this class' code off of) which works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just noticed your `checkboxVideoType` is a private property of this class, and I don't see a setter anywhere. If it's null, you'll get a NullPointerException which will cause a FC. You will need to pass a reference to the checkbox object (perhaps as a parameter to the `versionCheckbox()` method).

Comment: How will I code that? Something like versionCheckbox(Object checkboxVideoType) {      ?

Comment: Sure, but you can use the actual type instead of a generic object (to avoid having to type-cast), so: `versionCheckbox(CheckBox checkboxVideoType) {`

Comment: Okay, then in my main activity I get a "The method versionCheckbox(CheckBox) in the type VersionSettings is not applicable for the arguments ()"  What do I need to do with it there?

Comment: In the main activity, you should call it like this: `vs.versionCheckbox((CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.version_checkbox));` where `R.id.version_checkbox` is whatever ID you assigned in the layout.

Comment: Maybe the problem is that the checkbox itself is not in the main activity, but in another activity that I've set up as a preferences screen (not an actual preferences, just an activity with a layout and a checkbox). I just want to run the code in versionCheckbox() once when the app is started the first time to set the checkbox's SharedPreference value. Am I going about it poorly?

Comment: Would it be a better idea to put that code in the "preferences" activity and call it from there? Does it make a difference if that code is just in a class or in one that extends activity?

Comment: In that case, you won't be able to set the checkbox's state unelss the activity is visible (definitely will cause a FC), so I would strip that line (`checkboxVideoType.setChecked(nasaTV_Prefs.getBoolean("checkboxVideoType", false));`) from your `versionCheckbox()` method, and set it based on the value from the preferences when the activity housing the checkbox is created (`onCreate()`). This should solve it :)

Comment: Would the preferences activity have to be launched first, to create the checkbox, before I could set it then? I was hoping to be able to set it up on first launch with no user interaction. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: It would be set when the preferences activity is launched. BUT, if the activity is never launched, you don't need to worry about setting the checkbox, since the value is what matters, and that's stored in the SharedPreferences (which can be accessed from anywhere).

Comment: Can I have the SharedPreference set to a value on startup based on detected build_int, and have the checkbox in the preference activity set itself to the shared preference value that was stored on main activity start?

Comment: Okay, I'll start trying to figure that out. That's kind of what I've been trying to do, knowing that the checkbox and savedpreferences are somewhat separate will help. I put the main activity and preferences activity in the code up top also. Like I said, I'm very new to all of this, so it's all a massive learning experience. Thanks!

Comment: No problem; if you still have trouble with this, just let me know!

Comment: Don't mind the replies, I'm thinking aloud here. At the checkbox in Settings, it seems to be setting it to "true" all the time (checkboxVideoType.setChecked(nasaTV_Prefs.getBoolean("checkboxVideoType", true));). How do I make it set it to what's stored in SharedPreferences?

Comment: It seems the default value is called in Settings, is there a reason that the boolean isn't being written in the VersionSettings class?

Comment: In versionCheckbox() it's only allowing getDefaultSharedPreferences, in the other classes it's getSharedPreferences. Would this be causing a problem?